# Supporting same domain on two different apps supporting universal links..?

Tags: ios, iphone, branch.io, ios-universal-links

I have an application which supports universal links and it is currently in the app store.

Say it supports the domain www.example.com and thus universal links can be easily opened via this. We will have applinks:www.example.com in associated domains.

Now say if I want to release another app and it also supports the same domain. Now how will iOS distinguish which app to open via universal links..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, its pretty simple though.
My problem was that my first app was supporting all the pages by stating

"*" in the paths section of apple-app-site-association file. Now all I have to do is add NOT in front of one of the paths which I wanted my second app to handle.

like "NOT /cabs". I haven't tested it yet if this works or not. I will post an update as soon as I am done with it.

Comment: Wow, you accepted your own answer rather than the actual answer. Your "answer" should be a comment on the actual answer.

Comment: @David If you look carefully I answered almost a month before Vineet's answer and I accepted my answer before as it was the correct solution to the actual problem.

Comment: You are quite right. The order of the answers (in active view) confused me, I was sure that I checked the dates too but obviously not. I'm sorry for the tone of my comment.

Comment: @David No problem :)

Comment: Thanks Ankit, It saved my time for the research

Comment: So what is the answer? How are links handled by the OS if more than one App can use the same universal link? How do users choose the app that is going to be opened? Is this handled by the web site or the OS?

Comment: what about excluding subdomain instated of path?

Answer (score 27):

In order to supporting `Universal Links` with single domain on two different apps you need to make changes in your existing `apple-app-site-association` file, at https://{domain}/apple-app-site-association.

### For Single App Support

For single application support it's look like this

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234ABCDE.com.domain.myapp",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### For Multiple App Support

For multiple application support, you need add one more key-value pair in `details` array of `applinks` in `apple-app-site-association`. It's look like this

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appID": "1234ABCDE.com.domain.myApp",
                "paths": ["*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "1234ABCDE.com.domain.mySecondApp",
                "paths": ["*"]
            },
            {
                "appID": "1234ABCDE.com.domain.myThirdApp",
                "paths": ["*"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

### General Format of `apple-app-site-association` file

The file looks like this:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [ ],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "{app_prefix}.{app_identifier}",
            "paths": [ "/path/to/content", "/path/to/other/*", "NOT /path/to/exclude" ]
        },
        {
            "appID": "TeamID.BundleID2",
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

### References

[How to support Universal Links in iOS App and setup server for it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609667/how-to-support-universal-links-in-ios-app-and-setup-server-for-it)

Comment: There is a problem with your implementation of your apple-app-site-association file. All your apps are supporting "*", meaning all your apps can handle all the pages of the domain. This way the last app installed will opened every time a universal link is clicked.

Comment: That's the reason for adding general format for apple-app-site-association

Comment: what about excluding subdomain instated of path?

Answer (score 2):

**Apple App Site Association file example**

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [{
            "appID": "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.photoapp",
            "paths": ["/albums"]
            },
            {
            "appID": "D3KQX62K1A.com.example.videoapp",
            "paths": ["/videos"]
        }]
    }
}
```

**Important:** The order of the dictionaries in the array determines the order the system follows when looking for a match. The first match wins, allowing you to designate one app to handle specified paths within your website, and another app to handle the rest.

**References:**
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links

Comment: Does this works? Because I tried to accomplish the same scenario but it only open the same apps. @foskon