# Firebase dynamic links that open in multiple apps

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, apple-app-site-associate

I have previously used deeplinks to open in multiple apps depending on what the user has installed. I have now upgraded to dynamic links and can't figure out how to get this to work.
Currently it only opens in com.myapp

I have multiple apps (4 apps for both iOS and Android) that I want to be able to open a dynamic link in.
If one of the apps is installed then use that otherwise go to the appropriate store for the first app in the list.

It looks like you can only put one apn or ibi in the dynamic link.

Is this possible or will I have to revert back to using deeplinks for this purpose?

Long Dynamic link:

```
https://go.myapp.com/?link=https://member.myapp.com/register&apn=com.myapp&isi=appid&ibi=com.myapp
```

My AASA currently looks like this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "webcredentials": {
      "apps": [ "appid.com.myapp" ]
    },
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "appid4.com.myapp4",
        "paths": ["appname4/*"]
      },
      {
        "appID": "appid3.com.myapp3",
        "paths": ["appname3/*"]
      },
      {
        "appID": "appid2.com.myapp2",
        "paths": ["appname2/*"]
      },
      {
        "appID": "appid.com.myapp",
        "paths": ["*"]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Same issue in github:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/9542

EDIT 2:
From Firebase support:

> To give an overview, FDL can only support one app (iOS / Android /
> Web) per Firebase project. This is because the paths in the
> apple-app-site-association (AASA) file are /*, so the Dynamic Link
> will try to open the first app it sees in that list, and we don't have
> a way to guarantee how they are presented in the association. With
> that, the multiple apps associated with your Firebase project will
> cause reliability on navigating your Firebase Dynamic Links.
>
> For now, aside from using deeplinks, you can use a different project
> for the other apps so that you won’t experience opening behavior
> issues. You can also try the workarounds mentioned in this related
> Stack Overflow post.
>
> Lastly, we are aware that many developers, such as yourself, would
> like for FDL to support multiple apps. Please note that our team is
> exploring potential solutions to make this happen, and we have an
> internal feature request for this. As an action, I’ve linked your
> support ticket to let our engineering team know the increasing
> interest to have this type of feature implemented, though, I can't
> give any details or timeline as to when it will be available. For now,
> I suggest keeping an eye out on our official blog and release notes
> from time to time for any updates.

Same issue with some suggested workarounds which I have yet to try.
[Firebase Dynamic-Links is not working for different target in same project in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41582867/firebase-dynamic-links-is-not-working-for-different-target-in-same-project-in-io/61208739#61208739)